# Can i execute Azure webjobs without AzureWebJobsStorage connectionstring?

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, connection-string, azure-webjobs

When i create new Azure webjob project i could see the connectionstring section in `app.config` section as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- The format of the connection string is "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY" -->
    <!-- For local execution, the value can be set either in this config file or through environment variables -->
    <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

IN my webjob Functions im interacting only with my application db.

> 1. So Do i really need to create two more databases for azure webjobs ?

When i run webjobs from visual studio i'm getting the below error:

> Application: WebJobTest.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The     process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException Stack: at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Call(System.Reflection.MethodInfo,
>   System.Object) at WebJobTest.Program.Main()

And when i try access webjobs log it shows: WebJob Details WebJobTest

> Make sure that you are setting a connection string named
>   AzureWebJobsDashboard in your Microsoft Azure Website configuration by
>   using the following format
>   DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY
>   pointing to the Microsoft Azure Storage account where the Microsoft
>   Azure WebJobs Runtime logs are stored.

I guess this is because of not having proper database connection string.

> 2. What could be the possible connection between above two errors ?

Comment: Using azure storage for logs should not be required. I have web jobs that don't do that.

Comment: Both connection strings not required ? @MattfromStackify

Answer (score 6):

The **AzureWebJobsDashboard** connection string is optional - you only need it if you want to be able to use the Dashboard UI for logs, etc.

The **AzureWebJobsStorage** connection string IS required - while you might not be using any storage entities, the WebJobs runtime does use some blobs and other storage entities for its own tracking and operation.

Comment: can i use same `AzureWebJobsStorage` connectionstring for two webjobs?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same connection string for as many WebJobs as you want.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Mathew's answer, **AzureWebJobsStorage** is only required when using the WebJobs SDK, to use Azure WebJobs you don't have to use WebJobs SDK so you don't have to have **AzureWebJobsStorage** connection string.

Comment: So both connection strings not required ?Can i ignore both connection strings ? @Amit Apple

Comment: can i use same `AzureWebJobsStorage` connectionstring for two webjobs?

Comment: Yes, this is the default scenario